# Python nested loop and update set

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, nested, distance

I am a new student and now I am learning diversity in a set. I want to implement the greedy heuristic algorithm, this algorithm is quite easy, but I am stuck in the code.

Greedy heuristics generally make use of two sets: the set X of available items and the set S which contains the selected ones. Items are iteratively moved from X to S and vice versa until |S| = k. Items are moved one-by-one from X to S until k of them have been selected. The item that is moved each time is the one that has the maximum item-set distance `setdist` from S. The item-set distance/`setdist`, denoted as following:

[image]

The algorithm looks like this:
 [image]

This is my current code:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance

k = 5

# this is just sample set, the real set is complex. 
S = [1,9]
X = [3,4,5,6,7,8,103,1035,2009]

i = 1
while i < k:
    mylist =[]
    for a in range(0, len(X)):
        d = 0
        for b in range(0, len(S)):
            ed = distance.euclidean(X[a],S[b])
            if ed > d:
                d = ed
                listku = [(X[a],S[b]), d]
                #print(listku)
                mylist.append(listku)
                max_dis = max(mylist,key=lambda item:item[1])
    i = i + 1
```

From that code, I can get the max_dis, which is `[(2009, 1), 2008.0]` and I am stuck here.

The next step is, I want to take `2009` from `max_dis [(2009, 1), 2008.0]` then append to `S` and looping iteratively.

The expected output maybe: `[1,9,103,1035,2009]` this set is the optimum one/has max diverse.

Comment: Since your algorithm makes use of sets, wouldn't a good starting point be for you to use sets as well, as opposed to lists?  Then you could use set operations like `set.add()` and `set.remove()`

Comment: Thank you for this comment, I have transformed to set, but still get an issue about looping itself. Could you please help me? such as how to get the index of max value inside the nested loop? and soon

Comment: From your example, it sounds like, after the first pass, you want to remove `2009` from `X`, add it to `S`, then repeat.  If `X` and `S` are both sets, then you can do:  `S.add(2009)` and `X.remove(2009)`.  In your case, the `2009` would be `max_dis[0][0]`.

Comment: Hi @stucash I just guess the expected output, I dont think so 6 will be in S, in here, the output is S with 5 points and this S has the maximum distance/max diverse.

Comment: @user46543 sorry my bad, not 6. it seems like your algo here is to compare the distance between each element in X and in S, get the max distance pair. upon finding the X element that gives you the max distance, you add it to S and then you iterate again. so if that's your desired output, then the first time you find the max distance (i.e. 6), I think 3 should be added to S as well.

Comment: Hi @stucash did you read the my description above, the equation. Acctually, I want to compare all point in X to S, the max distance will be added to S, I guess, it will be `2009` because it has maximum distance to all members in S. then added `2009` to S, and check all point in X to S again, the point in X which has max distance to S:{1,9,2009} will be added until k = 5 or member in S equal to 5

Comment: Thank you @TomKarzes actually the reason I use lists is due to it easy to access the index. I am new in Python too. I am still trying with the set, but stuck in nested looping.

Comment: ok I think it's then a bit misleading. 103, 1035 will never be added your S. if you are guessing here we could only guess what you meant as well. you didn't explain why 103, 1035 were added to the list? if that's wrong/ doubtful then put it in your description. it's not about set or list here imo.

Comment: To be clear below answer was based on your description. so it’s finding max distance in each run which then will have 103,1035.

Answer (score 0):

```
from scipy.spatial import distance as dd


def test():
    k = 5

    # this is just sample set, the real set is complex.
    S = [1, 9]
    X = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 103, 1035, 2009]

    i = 1
    while i < k:
        mylist = []
        for a in xrange(len(X)):
            d = 0
            for b in xrange(len(S)):
                ed = dd.euclidean(X[a], S[b])
                if ed > d:
                    d = ed
                    listku = [(X[a], S[b]), d]
                    # print(listku)
                    mylist.append(listku)
                    max_dis = max(mylist, key=lambda x: x[1])
                    print "my list: "
                    print mylist
                    print "*************************************************"
                    print "max distance: "
                    print max_dis
            if max_dis[0][0] not in S:
                S.append(max_dis[0][0])
        print "----------------------------------"
        print "S: "
        print S
        i += 1


test()
```

final output for S:

```
S: [1, 9, 3, 8, 103, 1035, 2009]
```

**Explanation**

This prints, in each run, the element in X that gives you maximum distance, which then gets added to S.

`if statement` is actually union, it's only adding the unique element to S. 
and I can see this is what's expected in your algorithm setup (line 5).

you can see for yourself using the print statement to check whether you have achieved what you wanted here.

The algo psuedocodes look to me suggested something slightly different from what you have implemented; but that doesn't matter, you can later sort it out yourself.

**P.S.** This is in Python 2, you might want to change the print statements to use brackets.